# C# reading data from a csv file, with 8 columns, and sorting it

Tags: c#

So I am trying to read a csv file that essentially is a list of data separated by words, and I what I have done so far is used ReadAllLines and then from there separated with text.Split(',');
The only problem is I just read about this sort of list/array class method rather than creating an actual array, so I have no clue how to call it, or use it. Here is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
public class Earthquake
{
    public double Magnitude { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double depth { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public Earthquake(double magna, string locate, double lat, double longi, double dept, string dat, string Event, string website)
    {
        Magnitude = magna;
        Location = locate;
        Latitude = lat;
        Longitude= longi;
        depth = dept;
        date = dat;
        EventID = Event;
        URL = website;
    }

}
public class ManageData
{

    public int count;
    public void getData()
{
    string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(@"Earthquakes.csv");
    foreach (string word in text[count].Split(','))
    {
        //here i want to put each data in the Earthquake class
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Check this [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may replace

```
foreach (string word in text[count].Split(','))
    {
        //here i want to put each data in the Earthquake class
    }
```

with following code lines and see if it helps

```
foreach (string line in text)
{
  string[] myColumns = line.Split(',');

  EarthQuake eQ = new EarthQuake(myColumns[0],myColumns[1],myColumns[2],myColumns[3],myColumns[4],myColumns[5],myColumns[6],myColumns[7],myColumns[8]);
  //Add eQ into a list you want to save

}
```

This assumes the columns are in same order. If the order is different than rather than using this constructor, use default constructor and then assign values to the properties of EarthQuake class accordingly.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! However when I enter this in, it tells me that my Earthquake class has no arguments. Is there something wrong with my constructor?

Comment: @user1784655: Please give exact error/exception you got. I think myColumn[0] is string. Take String as argument of your constructor and then to Convert.ToDouble in the constructor for each argument.

Comment: Error 1 'Earthquake' does not contain a constructor that takes 9 arguments C:\Users\Micah Lee\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Earthquakes\Earthquakes\Earthquake Data.cs 39 25 Earthquakes

Comment: @user1784655: Okay your problem solved? If yes, mark it as answer/upvote. If no, do post issue you face.

Comment: I fixed that issue! I have another problem, in order to sort this, how would I call on the earthquake class in order to use it in a sorting method? for instance I want to sort it first by magnitude, then by depth, and potentially wanna use bubble sort method.

Answer (score 0):

This Project helped me a lot when I needed to manage CSV files, [C# CSV Reader and Writer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86973/C-CSV-Reader-and-Writer)

Comment: Thanks! but I on't want to use someone else's code! I wanna make my own! This does look useful though.

Comment: If you are doing it for a commercial purpose, I guess your idea should be changed, since you need to build from what the others finished, not start from scratch as they did, Anyway may be this was for a school work so I cannot interfere :) Good luck @user1784655