# taking data from a csv file, and putting it into an array

Tags: c#

```
public class Earthquake
{
    public double Magnitude { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double depth { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string EventID { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public Earthquake()
        : this(string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty)
    { }
    public Earthquake(string magna, string locate, string lat, string longi, string dept, string dat, string Event, string website)
    {
        Magnitude = Convert.ToDouble(magna);
        Location = locate;
        Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(lat);
        Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(longi);
        depth = Convert.ToDouble(dept);
        date = Convert.ToDateTime(dat);
        EventID = Event;
        URL = website;
    }

}


public void GetData()
    {

        string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(@"Earthquakes.csv");
            Earthquake[] data = new Earthquake[1];
            foreach (string line in text)
        {
            string[] myColumns = line.Split(',');
            Earthquake[] earth = new Earthquake[myColumns[0], myColumns[1], myColumns[2], myColumns[3], myColumns[4], myColumns[5], myColumns[6], myColumns[7]];
                data[i] = earth[i];
                i++;
        }
 }
```

Ignore commented parts I have those under control. The problem I am having is getting the data from the csv file into the Earthquake Array. I am getting syntax errors, and I know why, it's because the data type isn't correct, but I honestly cannot figure out how to fix it.
Also if you notice I am trying to use bubble sort and since there is no definition for "compare" for double, what do I use instead?

Comment: -1: did you really need to post so much code?

Comment: How is this different to your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577865/c-sharp-reading-data-from-a-csv-file-with-8-columns-and-sorting-it), ps I didn't upvote your question, do you have a buddy doing that?

Comment: someone told me to mark as answered and create a new one. I don't have buddies

Comment: Post only the relevent code, and post the exact error message(s) you get

Answer (score 1):

If your reading from CSV file you probably have to remove white space from the split values.

Try adding .Trim() to your column variables

```
myColumns[0].Trim()
```

if your looking to sort yor array consider using System.Linq

eg:

```
var byMag = earthQuakes.OrderBy(e => e.Magnitude);
```

Looking at your code you posted, GetData() will not work.

Try returning a list or Enumerable

```
 public IEnumerable<Earthquake> GetData(string filename)
     {
         string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
         foreach (string line in text)
         {
             string[] myColumns = line.Split(',');
             yield return new Earthquake(myColumns[0].Trim(), myColumns[1].Trim(), myColumns[2].Trim(), myColumns[3].Trim(), myColumns[4].Trim(), myColumns[5].Trim(), myColumns[6].Trim(), myColumns[7].Trim());
         }
     }
```

Usage:

```
var earthquakes = GetData(@"Earthquakes.csv");
```

Comment: wait what? I already know how to split the data, I just need to know how to put it into my earthquake array. Right now I am getting a lot of syntax errors due to it not being the right type of variable

Comment: ok, consider this "3,   4,   6" if you split by "," you wont be able to convert "   4" to int because numbers do not have white space.

Comment: ohhh I see what you're saying. Thanks!

Comment: @user1784655 - You need to load the correct data type.  There are hundreds of examples of how to read CSV files, I suggest doing some research, and posting more relavant code.  You don't even indicate what errors exactly, what lines they are, what debugging steps you did.

Comment: the variable "i" is not declared and you are trying to create a new Earthquake object using square brackets

Earthquake[] earth = new Earthquake[column[1],...] will not work at all.
also you are tryng to return Earthquake[] from Earthquake

Comment: Why do you have this Earthquake[] data = new Earthquake[1]; in your code, doesnt seem to be doing anything. Also you are doing 
data[i] = earth[i];, which will fail for any value of i other than 0. Please check your syntax first before posting your question.